# What's wrong with this conversion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

I need to calculate the following limes:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}
$$

My first intuition was that the answer is $x$, but after a bit of fiddling with the root I got thoroughly confused. I know that below conversion goes wrong somwhere, but where?

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1+x^2*n^2}{n^2}}
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2*n^2}}{n}
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}}{n}
= 0
$$

Comment: On the left hand side of the last equality, you need an "$n$" upstairs outside the radical ($\sqrt{1+x^2n^2}=\sqrt{n^2({1\over n^2}+x^2)}=n\sqrt{{1\over n^2}+x^2}$. Note though, you then have obtained exactly what you started with,

Comment: I wanna figure out the fact that the answer is $|x|$, not $x$.

Comment: @FrankScience: In general, for real $a$, $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$. This is because (for $w \ge 0$), $\sqrt{w}$ is defined to be the **non-negative** $s$ such that $s^2=t$.

Comment: Of course, given that nowhere it was stated from which set $x$ is taken (positive numbers, real numbers, complex numbers, or maybe something completely different), all one can say is that the result is $\sqrt{x^2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1+x^2 \cdot n^2}{n^2}}
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2 \cdot n^2}}{n}
\neq \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}}{n}
$$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{\frac{1+x^2 \cdot n^2}{n^2}}
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2 \cdot n^2}}{n}
= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}}{n}
$$

Comment: You need to cancel out the $n$ in the numerator and denominator to avoid $\infty/\infty$. Also, use \lim instead of just lim for the limit.

Comment: Sorry I have used CtrlC, CtrlV.

Comment: @RijulSaini: If you take the limit, there is no such thing as $\infty/\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2*n^2}}{n}
\not = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}+x^2}}{n}
$$ due to a factor of $n$.